# How to iterate and zip list elements between columns?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, list-comprehension

I am working with time-series data and tasked with binning rows based on a time condition and pulling out two specific column values: Type and Activity. I am trying to find the best way to zip the two lists and apply pd.valuecounts. I have attempted to write some list comprehension, but it's probably more complicated then it needs to be.

```
df['time_bin']= df.apply(time_mapping, axis=1) 

timebin_df = df.groupby('time_bin', as_index=False).agg(DocumentTypeDE ("DocumentTypeDE", 
list),DocumentEventDE=("DocumentEventDE",list), Counts=('DocumentEventDE', 'size'))
                                                                                                    
timebin_df
```

| timebin_df | DocumentTypeDE | DocumentActivity | DocumentType+ Activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30_days_before | [A1, A2] | [A1, A2] | [(A1,A1),(A,A2) ...] |

---

```
for x,y in zip(timebin_df['DocumentTypeDE'],timebin_df['DocumentEventDE']):
   zip_values = list(zip(x,y))
```

---

Ideally, I want to find a way to use this method:

#### Iterating over two columns, use `zip`

```
result = [f(x, y) for x, y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

---

Sample Output:

```
timebin_df       Tuple      Count        Mean

30_days_before  (A1,A1)       1            %
                (A1,A2)       1            %
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: can you paste some samples how your final results should look like

Comment: Added! The most important thing, in the end, is just trying to get elements and relative frequencies. Thank you.